# Checking nulls for the generic types

Tags: c#, asp.net, generic-type-argument, generic-function

I wanted to create a function, which will check the value of the parameter, if it's null it should set the value based on type of the parameter, else it should just return the value as it is.

Here what i have tried.

```
public static T ConvertNull<T>(T obj)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString()))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("COMING IN");
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Int32))
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(0, typeof(T));
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(DateTime.Now, typeof(T));
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(String.Empty, typeof(T));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("ELSE");
        return obj;
    }
}
```

But the problem is it always goes in ELSE section and returns Junk value.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the above function.

Comment: `Int` and `DateTime` are non-nullable.  It's not *possible* for them to be null.  You conversion of an empty string to any other arbitrary type `T` is also *highly* unlikely to succeed.  Most types in the world don't implement `IConvertable`.  Also anything that is `null` would just throw an exception when you called `ToString` on it.

Answer (score 0):

`String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString())` is very rarely going to be `true`.  THe only thing I can think of that will generate an empty string vi ToString() is another empty string.  In fact unless `ToString()` has been overridden (like it has been for native types like `DateTime` and `int`, you will get the fully qualified name of the object.

maybe you want

```
if (obj == default(T))
```

?

Comment: In that case, how shall i check the nulls for int and datetime

Comment: @Abbas `int` and `DateTime` _cannot_ be null.

Comment: `if (obj == default(T))` would turn, for example `DateTime.MinValue` for a date into `DateTime.Now`.  What if he really wanted the min date value, after all, they're not null?

Comment: @Servy - good point - the more I read the question the more confused I get.

Comment: ok, can anyone help with building a logic, i have some field in database like PublishDate, Views which supports datetime and int type, now if the field has null, and i try to read that value in cs code, it throws error "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.", i want that if they are null and if its datetime type it should return current date, if its int it should return 0

Answer (score 0):

If you have a nullable type that you want to replace with some value in the event that it is null, and return the existing value in the event that it is not-null, there is alerady an existing operator that does this, the `??` operator:

```
int? i = null;  //note of course that a non-nullable int cannot be null
int n = i ?? 0; //equals zero

string s = null;
string s2 = s ?? ""; //equals an empty string

string s3 = "hi";
string s4 = s3 ?? ""; //equals "hi"
```

Conveniently the `??` operator will not even compile in the event that the first operand's type is not nullable.